# Is it possible to integrate NUnit with VB.net Express Edition? Which is the best way?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, integration, visual-studio-express

I'm a Java Developer wich is learning VB.net for a small project. While coding in Java, we don't have to think a lot about how to integrate our IDE with our unit test framework because most of the IDEs already area integrated.

But now that I'm working on a project which the main requirement is to use VB.net Express Edition, is it possible to integrate this IDE with NUnit? How can I do that? Is there a better practice for this task? What should I do?

No, we can't opt to use Visual Studio, only the Express Edition of VB.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a test project, reference the nunit.framework DLL.  If you can set the startup program in express (via project properties), you can set the startup program for the test project to the NUnit framework GUI.  I wasn't sure if express supported that...

Additionally, you can run NUnit stand-alone; open NUnit, point to the test project DLL, and NUnit refreshes as you recompile.

HTH.

Comment: The project could have a build event that fires off nunit, although that's kinda clunky too.