# unit testing vb.net in VS2010 express

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express, vs-unit-testing-framework

What are some *easy* and *simple* unit testing frameworks to use with Visual Studio 2010 Express vb.net?

Are there any good tutorials geared towards this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be true anymore, but previous versions of VS Express weren't able to install *any* plugins.  This meant that you couldn't use the integrated test-runners, but that's really not that big of a deal.

Worst case is that you use VS to write your tests and compile both, then manually run your tests using their testrunner external to VS.  The most common unit-testing platform for .NET is nUnit which includes a standalone test runner.

Comment: nUnit isn't installed as a plugin -- it's installed as a project reference and an external tool.

Comment: @Michael -- correct, but most times it's used in conjunction with a plugin, so it's important to know that type of integration (likely) isn't offered for Express editions

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly [install nUnit for VS 2010 Express C#](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/setting-up-nunit-for-c-unit-testing-with-visual-studio-c-express-2008/) (I just tried this out this morning), so I would think you could for VB. The link is a tutorial/demo for VS Express 2008, but it worked in my Express 2010 -- again, C#.

I also found a older [tutorial using nUnit and VS 2005 Express VB](http://www.tertullian.org/rpearse/RightToLeft_Syriac/nUnitVBNet.htm)

**See also:**

- [Is
  it possible to integrate NUnit with
  VB.net Express Edition? Which is the
  best way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782806/is-it-possible-to-integrate-nunit-with-vb-net-express-edition-which-is-the-best)
- [Best
  way to do TDD in express versions of
  visual studio(eg VB Express)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258055/best-way-to-do-tdd-in-express-versions-of-visual-studioeg-vb-express)

---